# Post-processing multiple HTML files: Copy <h1> contents to <title> tag

Tags: html, gulp, sublimetext3, post-processing, harp

Suppose I have a number of compiled HTML-files from Harp, the static site generator.

My question:

**How do I post-process multiple HTML files, in each, automatically copying the contents of < h1> tag to the < title> tag?**

I'm wondering, if *Gulp* would be right for the job (and if so, how?), or if, perhaps, *Sublime Text 3* would have such feature built-in?

Answer (score 0):

hmm...well you **can** use gulp or grunt or any other build tool to do that.

You can also use some other text find-and-replace tools like sed.

if you need more stuff to do on your files (packging, post-processing, move, rename, ...) it makes sense to use gulp/grunt.

If you ended up using gulp/grunt you need to define a task which reads the content of those files and then does the replace and write to file. (a bit of nodejs knowledge is required + javascript basics)

Answer (score -1):

How about doing it dynamically onpage load?

```
var newtext = $("h1").text();
$("title").text(newtext);
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I would be prefer files that are static at "runtime", thus not dependent on JS (which might be turned off in the user's browser). Also, there could be issues with search engine web crawlers/SEO, if title tags are populated dynamically?